# How do I calculate the partial derivative with respect to $x$?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, backpropagation

I am trying to implement CNN using python NumPy. I searched so much, but all I found was for one filter with one channel for convolution.

Suppose $x$ is an image with the shape: `(N_Height, N_Width, N_Channel) = (5,5,3)`.

Let's say I have `16` filters with this shape: `(F_Height, F_Width, N_Channel) = (3,3,3)` , `stride=1` and `padding=0`

**Forward**:

The output shape after convolution 2d will be

```
(
math.floor((N_Height - F_Height + 2*padding)/stride + 1 )),
math.floor((N_Width- F_Width + 2*padding)/stride + 1 )),
filter_count
)
```

So, the output of this layer will be an array with this shape: `(Height, Width, Channel) =  (3, 3, 16)`

**BackPropagation**:

Suppose $dL/dh$ is the input for my layer in back-propagation with this shape: `(3, 3, 16)`

Now, I must find $dL/dw$ and $dL/dx$: $dL/dw$ to update my filters parameter and $dL/dx$ to pass it as input to the previous layer as the loss respect to the input $x$.

From this answer [Error respect to filters weights](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/45978/89170) I found how to calculate $dL/dw$.

The problem I have in the back-propagation is I don't know how to calculate $dL/dx$ having this shape: `(5, 5, 3)` and pass it to the previous layer.

I read lots of articles in Medium and other sites, but I don't get how to calculate it:

- [How Backpropagation works in a CNN](https://medium.com/@pavisj/convolutions-and-backpropagations-46026a8f5d2c)
- [The best explanation of Convolutional Neural Networks on the Internet!](https://medium.com/technologymadeeasy/the-best-explanation-of-convolutional-neural-networks-on-the-internet-fbb8b1ad5df8)
- [Backpropagation In Convolutional Neural Networks](https://www.jefkine.com/general/2016/09/05/backpropagation-in-convolutional-neural-networks/)
- [How to propagate error back to previous layer in CNN?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/28593/how-to-propagate-error-back-to-previous-layer-in-cnn?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

While this may not be the answer you were looking for, I hope this explanation will help you to understand applying backpropagation to a CNN. Fundamentally, convolutional layers are no different than dense layers, however there are restrictions. The key one is weight-sharing which allows a CNN to be much more efficient than a regular dense layer (as well as it being sparse due to locality). Imagine we are transforming a 4x4 image into a 2x2 image. Since we are inputting a 16-vector, and outputting a 4-vector, we need a weights matrix of 4x16:

[image]

This has 64 parameters. In a convolutional layer, we can accomplish this by convolving a 3x3 kernel over the image:

$$ K=
\begin{bmatrix}
k_{1,1} & k_{1,2} & k_{1,3} \\
k_{2,1} & k_{2,2} & k_{2,3} \\
k_{3,1} & k_{3,2} & k_{3,3}
\end{bmatrix} $$

This convolution is equivalent to multiplying by the weights matrix:

[image]

As you can see, this only requires 9 parameters and backpropagation can be applied to update these parameters.

Image Source: https://towardsdatascience.com/intuitively-understanding-convolutions-for-deep-learning-1f6f42faee1

Comment: thanks but as you said it is not my question's answer.
I finally find $dL/dX$ for each channel in my example ``16`` then I add all of them and 
I get my $dL/dX$